# Как воспроизвести видео при наведении на изображение?

Tags: javascript, html

Мне нужно что-бы при наведении на изображение, JS записывал HTML в DOM.
А когда мышку убираешь возвращается изображение и удаляется видео.
Я написал этот код [CodePen](https://codepen.io/brendan8c/pen/bGrEgKd).
Но он работает не корректно.

```js
let boxImage = document.querySelector(".picContainer") // Бокс с изображением
let image = document.querySelector(".image") // Изображение
const cod = '<video autoplay loop id="v0" muted width=500 preload="none" src="https://upread.ru/video/art144-1.mp4"></video>'

boxImage.addEventListener('mouseover', onVide);
boxImage.addEventListener('mouseout', offVide);

function onVide() {
    image.style.display = 'none';
    boxImage.innerHTML = cod;
}

function offVide() {
    image.style.display = 'block';
    let elem = document.getElementById("v0");
    elem.remove();
}
```

```css
.picContainer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 5px solid orange;
}
.image {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}
video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="picContainer">
<img class="image" src="https://images.hdqwalls.com/download/black-sun-horizon-4k-9n-3840x2400.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: "Но он работает не корректно." - ??

Comment: @igor Вы выполняли этот код или просто решили написать комментарий? Вы читали условия которые были в моём вопросе? Похоже, что нет.

Comment: Я  просто решил написать комментарий.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**video-box-1** - это div в котором лежит видео и изображение
**photo-1** - само изображение, которое мы видим изначально
**main-product__photo-off** - это класс в котором мы отключаем изображение (display: none;)
**video-1** - это видео которое появится при наведении на изображение
**main-product__video-on** - это класс в котором мы включаем видео (display: block;)

```
$(".video-box-1").hover(function() {
    $(".photo-1").addClass("main-product__photo-off");
    $(".video-1").addClass("main-product__video-on");
}, function() {
    $(".photo-1").removeClass("main-product__photo-off");
    $(".video-1").removeClass("main-product__video-on");
});
```

Comment: это ответ или дополнение к вопросу? // и отчего не по-русски?

Comment: Это решение моей проблемы на jQuery